# Trigger after update not working

Tags: sql, postgresql, triggers, sql-update

I'm struggling to get my 'after update' trigger to work properly.

As seen from my simple query, the sum of the production_work matches the sum of the order elements.

```
# select ident,ud,dp,swrv,sh,jmsw,sw,prrv,mhsw,bmsw,mp,pr,st,completed from orders;
 ident | ud | dp | swrv | sh | jmsw | sw | prrv | mhsw | bmsw | mp | pr | st | completed 
-------+----+----+------+----+------+----+------+------+------+----+----+----+-----------
     2 |  1 |  1 |    0 |  0 |    0 |  0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |  0 |  0 |  0 | f
(1 row)

# select * from production_work;
 ident | order_id | producer_id |    day     | ud | dp | swrv | sh | jmsw | sw | prrv | mhsw | bmsw | mp | pr | st 
-------+----------+-------------+------------+----+----+------+----+------+----+------+------+------+----+----+----
     5 |        2 |           1 | 2013-08-09 |  1 |  0 |    0 |  0 |    0 |  0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |  0 |  0 |  0
     6 |        2 |           2 | 2013-08-09 |  0 |  1 |    0 |  0 |    0 |  0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |  0 |  0 |  0
(2 rows)
```

I'm trying to set the 'completed' to true if the sum of the work elements match the order element by using this trigger:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION update_order_completion_status() RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$
BEGIN
    WITH w AS (
            SELECT SUM(ud) AS ud, SUM(dp) AS dp, SUM(swrv) AS swrv, SUM(sh) AS sh, SUM(jmsw) AS jmsw, SUM(sw) AS sw, SUM(prrv) AS prrv,
                    SUM(mhsw) AS mhsw, SUM(bmsw) AS bmsw, SUM(mp) AS mp, SUM(pr) AS pr, SUM(st) AS st
            FROM production_work
            WHERE order_id = OLD.order_id
    ), o AS (
            SELECT ud, dp, swrv, sh, jmsw, sw, prrv, mhsw, bmsw, mp, pr, st
            FROM orders
            WHERE ident = OLD.order_id
    )
    UPDATE orders
    SET completed = (w.ud = o.ud AND w.dp = o.dp AND w.swrv = o.swrv AND w.sh = o.sh AND w.jmsw = o.jmsw AND w.sw = o.sw AND
                    w.prrv = o.prrv AND w.mhsw = o.mhsw AND w.bmsw = o.bmsw AND w.mp = o.mp AND w.pr = o.pr AND w.st = o.st)
    WHERE ident = OLD.order_id;
END;
$BODY$ LANGUAGE plpgsql ;

CREATE TRIGGER update_order_completion_status_trigger
AFTER UPDATE OF ud, dp, swrv, sh, jmsw, sw, prrv, mhsw, bmsw, mp, pr, st
ON production_work
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE update_order_completion_status();
```

I'm not getting any error messages when I do the update to the production_work table, but as you can see the completed column is not being set to true.

Comment: Missing: table definition (`\d` in psql), version of Postgres.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SQL query in your trigger func is needlessly complicated and also incorrect (missing `FROM` clause in `UPDATE`). A simplified, correct version would be:

```
UPDATE orders o
SET    completed = (w.ud = o.ud AND w.dp = o.dp AND ...)
FROM (
    SELECT SUM(ud) AS ud, SUM(dp) AS dp, ...
    FROM   production_work
    WHERE  order_id = NEW.order_id
    ) w
WHERE  o.ident = NEW.order_id
AND    o.completed <> (w.ud = o.ud AND w.dp = o.dp AND ...);
```

Assuming `completed NOT NULL`.

Note, I am using [**`NEW`**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/trigger-definition.html), not OLD, since you want to use the new values.
But if `production_work.order_id` can change, you'd have to update `orders` for `OLD` *and* `NEW`.

The last line is to prevent empty updates.

#### Alternative: VIEW

If you don't need the redundant column `completed` to optimize performance, I would consider a [**VIEW**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-createview.html) instead:

```
CREATE VIEW order_plus AS
SELECT o.*, (SUM(w.ud) = o.ud AND SUM(w.dp) = o.dp AND ...) AS completed
FROM   orders o
JOIN   production_work w ON o.ident = w.ident
GROUP  BY o.ident;
```

Assuming `ident PRIMARY KEY`.

Comment: Thank you so much.  Clearly I'm going to have to go back and look at UPDATE syntax again.   I like your idea of the extended view and went with that as my solution.